# Personalizar cursor com css

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber como eu altero o cursor, botando uma imagem que eu quero, é possível ?

Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

### CSS?

```
#esquerda{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    cursor: url(imagens/cursor-154478__180.png);
}
```

porém não acontece nada, mas se eu mudar a parte da url em diante para um `crosshair` ele funcionam, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: A url precisa usar aspas unicas. `cursor: url('imagens/cursor-154478__180.png');`

Comment: Num precisa não.

Comment: Na função `url` você deve usar aspas e começar o valor com um '/', indicando a pasta root. Exemplo: `cursor: url('/imagens/cursor-154478__180.png');`

Answer (score 4):

você precisa definir qual cursor receberá a imagem

```css
#esquerda{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    cursor: url(http://i225.photobucket.com/albums/dd43/erickson_29/basic.gif), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="esquerda"></div>
```

Essas são todas as opções de cursores que você possui:

```
auto            
default         
none            
context-menu    
help            
pointer         
progress        
wait            
cell            
crosshair       
text            
vertical-text   
alias           
copy            
move            
no-drop         
not-allowed     
all-scroll      
col-resize      
row-resize      
n-resize        
e-resize        
s-resize        
w-resize        
ns-resize       
ew-resize       
ne-resize       
nw-resize       
se-resize       
sw-resize       
nesw-resize     
nwse-resize
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito !!

Comment: Marca como certa, basta clicar no "V" em baixo da pontuação, isso vai ajudar outras pessoas que busquem uma dúvida como essa a saber qual foi a resposta que resolveu seu problema e de lambuja ainda incentiva quem te ajudoy dando a ele reputação.
:D