# Mudar a barra do cursor num campo de edição com CSS JS ou JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Olá, gostaria de mudar (estilizar) a barra do cursor (piscante) em campos de edição em páginas HTML. Não o cursor, mas sim a barra do cursor. Pesquisei bastante aqui no SOPT e achei discussões e dicas bem interessantes mas apenas sobre o cursor, a exemplo: [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81967/personalizar-cursor-com-css?rq=1), [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3653/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-trocar-a-cor-do-cursor-do-mouse-via-css) e também [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330895/cursor-do-mouse-javascript-e-css). Enfim, só consegui algo próximo da minha colocação, com uma pergunta e resposta sobre Android, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138447/como-mudar-a-cor-do-cursor-brilhante-do-edittext). Pergunto, não é possível no CSS, JS ou JQuery? O último link, que está com o tópico de assunto como [Android] é específico do Java, tipo, para o Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se tem outros tipos de customização mas conheço o `caret-color`

```css
input {
  caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
```

Comment: Giovanni Dias, então... não  conhecia esse atributo, e é bem interessante, a princípio, mas quero algo além, tipo, mudar o formato da barra em si.

Comment: acredito que vc possa fazer um cursor utilizando uma div pra acompanhar o texto ou algo do tipo como aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758023/how-to-use-this-square-cursor-in-a-html-input-field mas acho que mudar o caret em si não há como

Comment: puxa, Giovanni Dias... valeu mesmo pela atenção. Deu uma adiantada boa. Vou deixar a pergunta ainda em aberto, quem sabe!